# Spring integration tests : how to use context-caching?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a base class for all my integration tests, which is something like this :

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config1.class, Config2.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "zonky.test.database.postgres.docker.image=my-image",
        "spring.profiles.active=test"
})
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
public abstract class IntegrationTestBaseConfiguration {
}
```

Now, in each individual test class I have :

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config3.class})
class ConcreteIntegrationTest extends IntegrationTestBaseConfiguration {

  //tests
}
```

I want to know if the context defined in the `IntegrationTestBaseConfiguration` is reused and shared among all my integration tests ?

If not, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: No it isn't re-used and you cannot share that as that context isn't created. It creates a context for your specific test, which is based on the combinded configuration of both tests.

Comment: thanks for your replay. Is there a way to know if a context is cached and reused ?

Comment: That is build in and automatically active, you can enable debug logging. But as stated there is only one context here not 1 for the abstract/parent and one for the child. Just one consisting of the combined configuration.